# Can't get an IP for wlan0

Tags: raspbian, wireless, dhcp

So `wlan0` is connecting fine to my router, but I'm not getting an IP.

`/etc/network/interfaces` has the line:

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

Changing `manual` to `dhcp` doesn't seem to help, I get lots of messages of the form:

```
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
```

And eventually it fails. Perhaps it's looking in the wrong place? I'm fine to either configure a static IP or get DHCP working.

As requested, `ifconfig wlan0`:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:f3:c1:0f:18:50
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:75 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:4416 (4.3 KiB)
```

wpa_gui:

[image]

Comment: Check the second line of output from `ifconfig wlan0`.

Comment: @goldilocks I've added the whole thing

Comment: TX bytes with no RX bytes very strongly implies you *don't* have any kind of connection.  Why do you believe that you do?

Comment: @gold The raspbian utility told me everything was ok...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `/etc/network/configuration` to:

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
address 192.168.1.66
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Set a static IP, which worked.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Still, how should I configure wlan0 to get a dynamic address via DHCP?

Answer (score 1):

## Setting a static IP Address

Assuming you want to assign a manual IP Address, edit the interfaces configuration file, restart the interface, and check your IP address.

#### 1. Open interface config file with `nano`

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

#### 2. Specify static IP address

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.127
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.128
    netmask 255.255.255.0

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

#### 3. Restart the `wlan0` interface

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

#### 4. Verify that the manual IP Address is assigned

Type the following in the terminal:

```
ifconfig
```

#### Expected Result

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:192.168.1.127  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2464 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:316409 (308.9 KiB)  TX bytes:177184 (173.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7394 (7.2 KiB)  TX bytes:7394 (7.2 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:192.168.1.128  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:510 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:164607 (160.7 KiB)  TX bytes:11984 (11.7 KiB)
```